# inconsistent look in two installations of eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have done a fresh install of eclipse mars on both of my desktop PC and laptop PC. While the user interface looks clean on desktop PC, it looks ugly (compared to Desktop) on laptop. Both PC's have same configuration. Both runs Linux Mint 17.2 as operating system. Both uses same GTK theme etc. In my opinion the problem in laptop is backgrounds of SWT widgets are not transparent. But this is just a guess.

Screenshot of Desktop PC
[image]

screen shot of laptop PC
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your opinion seems to be right. I had a same problem on Kubuntu. In fact I couldn't change it in any way. After few days it looks right by itself. (maybe some fix, update or something...)
*By the way nice interface!*

Comment: thanks, I will not waste time trying to fix it. Hopefully, it will be fixed one day with updates. But it is annoying until then. Not much for me, as I do not code in laptop often.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was a GTK theme issue, not an eclipse issue. Although two  PC's use the same GTK theme (delorean dark). Desktop PC was getting the theme from a more updated PPA. laptop was getting the theme from Linux Mint PPA. I updated the theme on laptop, now the looks are consistent.